# write dataframe from jupyter notebook to snowflake without define table column type

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a data frame in jupyter notebook. My objective is to import this df into snowflake as a new table.

Is there any way to write a new table into snowflake directly without defining any table columns' names and types?

i am using

```
import snowflake.connector as snow
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

connection = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='XXX',
    password='XXX',
    account='XXX',
    warehouse='COMPUTE_WH',
    database= 'SNOWPLOW',
    schema = 'DBT_WN'
    )


df.to_sql('aaa', connection, index = False)
```

it ran into an error:
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments converted during string formatting

**Can anyone provide the sample code to fix this issue?**

Comment: the schema of `df` is the same as 'DBT_WN' schema ?

Comment: @BlackRaven yea,  table should be save as 'SNOWPLOW'.DBT_WN'.'aaa'

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it  -- apologies in advance for my code formatting in SO combined with python's spaces vs tabs "model". Check the tabs/spaces if you cut-n-paste ...

Because of the Snowsql security model, in your connection parameters be sure to specify the ROLE you are using as well. (Often the default role is 'PUBLIC')

Since you already have sqlAlchemy in the mix ... this idea doesn't use the snowflake write_pandas, so it isn't a good answer for large dataframes ... Some odd behaviors with sqlAlchemy and Snowflake; make sure the dataframe column names are upper case; yet use a lowercase table name in the argument to to_sql() ...

```
def df2sf_alch(target_df, target_table):
   # create a sqlAlchemy connection object
   engine = create_engine(f"snowflake://{your-sf-account-url}",
                        creator=lambda:connection)
   # re/create table in Snowflake
   try:
       # sqlAlchemy creates table based on a lower-case table name
       #      and it works to have uppercase df column names
       target_df.to_sql(target_table.lower(), con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
       print(f"Table {target_table.upper()} re/created")
   except Exception as e:
       print(f"Could not replace table {target_table.upper()}", exc_info=1)
   nrows = connection.cursor().execute(f"select count(*) from {target_table}").fetchone()[0]
   print(f"Table {target_table.upper()} rows = {nrows}")
```

Note this function needs to be changed to reflect the appropriate 'snowflake account url' in order to create the sqlAlchemy connection object. Also, assuming the case naming oddities are taken care of in the df, along with your already defined connection, you'd call this function simply passing the df and the name of the table, like `df2sf_alch(my_df, 'MY_TABLE')`